# Strange Value for MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE and MF_MT_H264_MAX_MB_PER_SEC

Tags: media, ms-media-foundation

I am trying enumerate Video Capture format for Logitech camera.I am using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I got following entries

MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE                        640 x 480
MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE                       6619136
MF_MT_COMPRESSED                        1
MF_MT_H264_MAX_MB_PER_SEC               245,0,245,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE                        MFMediaType_Video
MF_MT_H264_SUPPORTED_USAGES             3
MF_MT_H264_SUPPORTED_RATE_CONTROL_MODES 15
MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE                    {2017BE05-6629-4248-AAED-7E1A47BC9B9C}
MF_MT_H264_SUPPORTED_SYNC_FRAME_TYPES   2
MF_MT_MPEG2_LEVEL                       40
MF_MT_H264_SIMULCAST_SUPPORT            0
MF_MT_MPEG2_PROFILE                     256
MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES                0
MF_MT_H264_CAPABILITIES                 33
MF_MT_FRAME_RATE                        30 x 1
MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO                1 x 1
MF_MT_H264_SUPPORTED_SLICE_MODES        14
MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT           0
MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN              30 x 1
MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE                    2
MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX              30 x 1
MF_MT_H264_RESOLUTION_SCALING           3
MF_MT_H264_MAX_CODEC_CONFIG_DELAY       1
MF_MT_SUBTYPE                           MFVideoFormat_H264_ES
MF_MT_H264_SVC_CAPABILITIES             1

**Note:** I have modified the function in [Media Type Debugging Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663602%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as follows.when i run the program i got cElement = 10 and i have put pElemet in for loop to get this value MF_MT_H264_MAX_MB_PER_SEC 245,0,245,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

```
case VT_VECTOR | VT_UI1:
{
        //DBGMSG(L"<<byte array Value>>");
        // Item count for the array.
        UINT  cElement = var.caub.cElems/sizeof(UINT);
        // Array pointer.
        UINT* pElement = (UINT*)(var.caub.pElems);
        for( int i = 0; i < cElement;i++)           
            DBGMSG(L"%d,", pElement[i]);

}
```

I am not able to find out what these value signifies

1. MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE    {2017BE05-6629-4248-AAED-7E1A47BC9B9C}
2. MF_MT_H264_MAX_MB_PER_SEC   245,0,245,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

Answer (score 0):

MSDN explains value of [MF_MT_H264_MAX_MB_PER_SEC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute:

> Data type
>   UINT32[] stored as UINT8[]

Hence, array of bytes is the expected formatting.

> The value of the attribute is an array of UINT32 values, which correspond to the following fields in the UVC 1.5 H.264 video format descriptor.

You have:

> dwMaxMBperSecOneResolutionNoScalability
>
> Specifies the maximum macroblock processing rate allowed for
>   non-scalable Advanced Video Coding (AVC) streams, summing up across
>   all layers when all layers have the same resolution.

**16056565**

> dwMaxMBperSecTwoResolutionsNoScalability
>
> Specifies the maximum macroblock processing rate allowed for
>   non-scalable AVC streams, summing up across all layers when all layers
>   consist of two different resolutions.

**0**

Comment: what is this guid value{2017BE05-6629-4248-AAED-7E1A47BC9B9C}

Answer (score 0):

Media Type GUID "2017be05-6629-4248-aaed-7e1a47bc9b9c" means FORMAT_UVCH264Video
You can then cast the pbFormat struct to KS_H264VIDEOINFO*